# I'm not seeing any POST requests when I run my Blazor Server App

Tags: post, blazor, fiddler

I'm running a blazor server app that has been deployed to IIS. The site has a REST web service as it's back end. The code is something like this:

```
<EditForm Model="@boundObject" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" @bind="boundbject.HasCar" />
    </td>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {

    private void HandleValidSubmit(object handler)
    {
        if(boundObject.HasCar)
        {
            webService.WriteHasCar(boundObject.objectID,true)   
        }   
    }

}
```

It works just fine but looking at the network traffic in Fiddler when I submit this request, I can see the PATCH request going to the webService that the call to the web service does, but I'm not seeing a POST request for when I hit the submit button. What am I missing here? Is the Fiddler trace failing to see it or will my code not generate a POST request? And if it doesn't, how is the value of the checkbox getting to the server?

Comment: You are sending a patch and expecting it to be a post? POST, PUT, PATCH, GET, DELETE are all different. PATCH is not very common these days but still supported.

Comment: The patch occurs at the line webService.WriteHasCar when this web app pushes to the back end web service. I'm asking why I don't see a post request when I hit submit. I see the traffic between my web app and the web service. The traffic I'm not seeing is the post request between the browser and this web app.

Comment: If its sending a PATCH your controller needs a PATCH method. For example using [HttpPatch("{id:int}")] attribute.

Comment: I think you're getting hung up on the PATCH. The PATCH is just fine. What I'm asking is why I don't see a POST request when I submit a form on a blazor server app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't see a Post request because no post request is made. Your form is not submitted. No traditional post request occurs though you're using a submit button.
The submit action is intercepted by Blazor and cancelled, as this is an SPA application with well-defined space boundaries. You usually do not navigate out of these boundaries, and if you do, as for instance, navigating to an external login page, your SPA does not exist any longer. When you are redirected back, it is resurrected...

Server Blazor Apps do not use the HTTP protocol, but rather SignalR. All the communications between the client-side (browser) and server-side of Server Blazor App is perform via SignalR.

Note that the initial request to your App is an HTTP get request. This is the only time HTTP is used and not SignaR

Comment: Thanks enet, that's the kind of answer I was looking for. I thought it was probably something fundamental to Blazor. Can you recommend any readings on what SignalR is and how Blazor works with it?

Comment: @yellephen According to the documentation SignalR will use WebSockets when it's available. Therefore a proxy with WebSocket support should work. According to the [Fiddler documentation](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/what-s-new-in-fiddler-4-5)) WebSockets should be supported (can't find it at the moment in the latest Fiddler version).